# Set a flag on message for identification

Tags: python, discord.py

I am looking for a way to set a flag or some kind of identifier on a `discord.Message` object so that later, for example if a reaction is added, I could identify it as a certain type and do something with it. I need something similar to `discord.MessageFlags`, but with the option to set the key myself, or ideally even make it of arbitrary type (not Just `Boolean`).
Is there anything built in that I could use, or some hacky solution?

Also, if someone asks, I don't want to set up a database.

Edit: Alternatively is there a way to see if a certain bot command have sent a particular message?

Comment: why don't you save the ids in a database and use those instead ?

Comment: You could add a reaction to the message.  So if your bot account reacted to a message with a particular emoji that would be your flag.

Comment: I gues I could use an emoji, but as I last resort. I have a bot command in mind that will use emojis for counting some stuff and I don't want to make it too confusing. And also using an emoji doesn't seem very reliable, even if it's a very obscure one.

Comment: Another solution could be to just store the message ids in some file